# ArrayBuffer has no data when using the incoming data

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I am making an array buffer from a stream of binary data received from a websocket object's server.

When I view the 'msg' object I see that it is full of the data. 
After initializeing my buffer object with 'new ArrayBuffer(msg.data) When I view the 'buffer' object I see that it is empty, size = 0.

I understand that arraybuffer is a supposed 'black box' and must be viewed with a typed array object. But it says the array buffer is empty. It also said that a view object which I set using 'new DataView(buffer);' is showing empty and of size 0 as well.

I also tried setting the binaryType property of the websocket object handler on both the server and the client side to be "arraybuffer" with ---

```
this.socket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
```

Here is my code:

```
 this.socket.onmessage = function(msg){  

          let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(msg.data);
```

even when I tried setting the msg.data directly to a uintarray like this it still turned up an empty object:

```
let buffer = new Uint8Array(msg.data);
```

Comment: JavaScript's [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) has one constructor which takes the `size`, in bytes, of the array buffer to create. Try `new ArrayBuffer(msg.data.length);` and then write values byte by byte.

Comment: But then how do i set the contents of array buffer to be equal to the message.data? With a for loop that iterates over the two?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Give it a try and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: So that worked to make the array buffer and fill it with the data bits. But now when I create a view object with either 'new DataView(buffer,0,buffer.length)' or new UInt8Array(buffer, 0, buffer.length) it doesn't fill these objects properly. For instance, the data view seems to get created with absolutely nothing in it. The UInt8Array gets created with the correct number of elements, but every element is just a 0. Do you know what would be going on here or what the proper way to do use these objects would be?

Comment: It should work if you are doing it correctly. Follow the example in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) and try again. If still isn't working, then ask a new question about writing from `ArrayBuffer` to `DataView` by providing what you tried with a reproducible example.